# Site in offline mode, any way to debug how this happened?

Tags: 6, users, debugging, maintenance-mode

I came in this morning to find my companies site in offline mode. I personally checked with the only other site admin, and none of other users have the ability to turn off the site. I was using the Backup module prior to me leaving last night, but I've backed up hundreds of times and never encountered the module leaving the site in Offline mode.

Would there be any logs or any location in the database where this activity might be logged? We don't allow users to login to our Drupal site, just our own editors and a

I've tired Googling answers but I haven't got very far :(

running Drupal 6.x

Comment: Can you check any server error logs? Also, is there any specific message on the offline page? Anything to do with the database for example?

Comment: Hi, would you recommend that I check the server logs or the php error logs? It just was the general "Site is in offline mode" message. The problem was resolved by logging in as User0, and turning the site back on. My managers probably require a better answer then it turned it self off. ;)

Comment: You could check the PHP error logs to see if there was some sort of memory limit or database issue that knocked it off?

Answer (score 4):

Site offline is a matter of a global variable `site_offline` set to `1`. Any call of `variable_set('site_offline', '1')` can also result to put site into offline mode.

Invalid database configuration can also results as site offline but it adds some error message.

Unauthorized access to DB can be used to manually alter record in `variable` table for the values as
variable.name='site_offline', variable.value='s:1:"1"'

Answer (score 1):

The script for Updating a module in administration menu can take the site offline as well.

Comment: This is valid for D7, D6 does not behave in that way (AFAIK)

Answer (score 0):

A site restored from a backup produced with the backup_migrate module is automatically placed in offline mode. This is presumably a protection to allow an administrator to adjust configuration settings before the site is made generally available. Is it possible the site was restored from backup?